# Shuffle letters in word. javascript

Tags: javascript, shuffle

I need to shuffle the letters in a word, but I can't change the position of the first and last letters.

And this is my function for shuffelWord:

```
function shuffelWord(word) {
        var shuffledWord = '';
        word = word.split('');
        console.log("word", word);
        while (word.length > 0) {
            shuffledWord += word.splice(word.length * Math.random() << 0, 1);
        }
        return shuffledWord;
    }
```

What I am doing wrong?

---

Answer (score 2):

You can so something like:

```js
function shuffelWord(word) {
  word = word.split('');

  //Remove the first and the last letter
  let first = word.shift();
  let last = word.pop();

  //Shuffle the remaining letters
  for (let i = word.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [word[i], word[j]] = [word[j], word[i]];
  }

  //Append and return
  return first + word.join("") + last;
}

let test = shuffelWord('javascript');

console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taking all the word's letters in an array, exclude the first and last from that. Also use another variable for that array, so that you still have access to the original word and can append the first and last character again:

```
function shuffelWord(word) {
    var shuffledWord = '';
    var letters = word.split('').slice(1, -1); // exclude first and last
    while (letters.length > 0) {
        shuffledWord += letters.splice(letters.length * Math.random() << 0, 1);
    }
    return word[0] + shuffledWord + word[word.length-1]; // include first and last
}
```